# Receiving EADDRINUSE error after switching to https

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, https, port

Since switching my React app to https, after running `npm start` I am receiving this error in the logs:

```
0|server   |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
0|server   |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
0|server   |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/fsadmin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.1/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
0|server   |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
0|server   |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
0|server   |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
0|server   |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
0|server   |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
0|server   |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
0|server   |   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
0|server   |   errno: -98,
0|server   |   syscall: 'listen',
0|server   |   address: '::',
0|server   |   port: 443
0|server   | }
```

After some research I learned that the error code `EADDRINUSE` means that the port number which `listen()` tries to bind the server to is already in use, in my case `443`.

I then learned that I could run this line `sudo lsof -i tcp:443` to see which processes were currently running on port 443 and I received the following output:

```
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   1565538     root    6u  IPv6 4765556      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx   1565538     root    7u  IPv4 4765557      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx   1565539 www-data    6u  IPv6 4765556      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx   1565539 www-data    7u  IPv4 4765557      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx   1565540 www-data    6u  IPv6 4765556      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx   1565540 www-data    7u  IPv4 4765557      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx   1565540 www-data   22u  IPv4 4777936      0t0  TCP mydomain:https->ip68-96-216-193.lv.lv.cox.net:59805 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   1565541 www-data    6u  IPv6 4765556      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx   1565541 www-data    7u  IPv4 4765557      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx   1565542 www-data    6u  IPv6 4765556      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx   1565542 www-data    7u  IPv4 4765557      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
```

I then made the error of killing these processes which resulted in losing all accessibility to my site.

I have since gone through the deployment process again and my site is back online however I am in the same position and receiving the same error. Is anyone aware of a way to solve this?

Comment: Also have a look at `netstat -lntp`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said about "your app" and "your site", when you made the config change the app, you created a classic "port conflict".

Basically, your site is a process using port 443.

When you switched on HTTPS, the app wanted to use 443 (because that's the default).

Classically, only one process can listen to a port, so the 2nd process will error when it tries to bind.

The quick fix, esp. if this is not in production, is to let it listen on :443.

If this is a serious project, then you probably want to see if the app can live inside your web site... (probably worthy of a new question in ServerFault.)